# Is it necessary to use a plt.bar() to center labels in a log histogram?

Tags: python, data-visualization, histogram, logarithm

I have been struggling to center the labels under the histogram bars in this log plot.  Specifically, I was hoping for the first bar to be over the "1" as this is the first value.

All of the solutions online seem to suggest using the plt.bar() function, which I haven't gotten to work correctly with the log scale and bin size. Do I need to start over from scratch with a bar graph? Any other tips for fixing this to center the histogram? A link to the data is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1USxTNcxveKoM1X_-TTn6ZX4GcUdRm2a7/view?usp=sharing. The code and current figure are below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

MJ = pd.read_excel('MJ1a_data.xlsx')
hist = plt.hist(x = MJ.MJ1a, 
bins=np.logspace(start=np.log10(1), stop=np.log10(10000), num=25), rwidth = .7)
plt.gca().set_xscale('log')
plt.xticks(ticks = [1,10,100,1000,10000],labels = [1,10,100,1000,10000], horizontalalignment = 'center', fontname = "Arial", fontsize = 14, fontweight = 'medium')
plt.yticks(fontname = "Arial", fontsize = 14, fontweight = 'medium')
plt.xlabel("Total Lifetime MJ Use", fontname = 'Arial', fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel("Frequency", fontname = 'Arial', fontsize = 14)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **histogram** and a **bar plot** are different plot types for different situations. A histogram is used to show the approximate distribution of a continuous variable, whereas a bar plot is used to compare the frequencies of several categories.

Since your x-variable is continuous, a histogram is definitely the right choice over a bar plot. But now you are apparently trying to make the histogram look like a bar plot. I would strongly recommend to not do that, because it would be misleading.

Specifically, don't set the width to a lower value. The "bars" are supposed to touch each other in a histogram, because they show densities for the specified bins, and there are no gaps between the bins. The `1` should **not** be centered under the first "bar", because it is the left border of the first bin. Centering it would imply that it were the average value within the first bin.